# How to sort a dask dataframe in descending order?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dask, dask-dataframe

Apparently, the ascending keyword does not exist in `dask`, which is funny because `dask` is designed to resemble `pandas`. This does not work:

```py
res = (ddf
    .groupby(['An important column'])
    .mean()
    .sort_values('Score', ascending=False)
    .compute()
)
```

What would be the best way to do that descending sorting with `dask`?

```
> NotImplementedError: The ascending= keyword is not supported
```

dask version: `2021.4.0`

Answer (score 1):

If the delayed result is very small (fits in worker/client memory) and has a task graph that does not involve a lot of data shuffling, then it’s usually OK to run `.compute` first (to turn the delayed value into pandas df) and then run the missing/not implemented function.

For example, this could be done as follows:

```py
res = (ddf
    .groupby(['some_col'])
    .agg({'Score': 'mean'})
    .compute()
    .sort_values('Score', ascending=False)
)
```

Sorting across partitions is an expensive operation:

```py
res = (ddf
    .sort_values('some_col', ascending=False)
)
```